# FF4 problem with use window event onResize

Tags: javascript, html, events, firefox4

We have some problem with FF4 when add event. Look like than our event is catched and freezed. And in final we have gray screen on FF4

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addEvent(elem, type, eventHandle) {
    if (elem == null || elem == undefined) return;
    if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
        elem.addEventListener( type, eventHandle, false );
    } else if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
        elem.attachEvent( "on" + type, eventHandle );
    }
};

addEvent(window, "resize", function() { alert("hello there!");  } );
</script>
</head>
<body>
test resize page
</body>
</html>
```

And it`s normal work in IE7, Chrome, FF3

Comment: The preferred abbreviation for Firefox is "Fx" or "fx"

Answer (score 0):

`alert("hello there!");`

I think it freezes your page. It's called too many times.

See example with input field http://jsfiddle.net/FbEhD/.
It shows how many times event handler is called.